# how to find the sum of all the values in an int[][] Java?

Tags: java, int

i have an array of integer arrays 'int pixels[][]'

and i want to find the sum of all of them so i can find the average pixel value

this will be used so that i can set the average value of a pixel to be the threshold value for a pbm image

if the value if above threshold i will export a white pixel if its below i will export a black one (just to give some context)

i assume the code below is not correct at all as the output it 6.0 but i think its something like this

```
   double threshold = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
   {
       threshold += (double)pixels[i][i];
   }
   System.out.print(threshold);
```

Comment: Iterate over every row, and iterate over every cell to add all up. You need nested loops for that.

Comment: You can use 2 nested loops to reach all elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to iterate all number in arrays,you can try with this:

```
           double threshold = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
           {
               for(int j=0;j<pixels[i].length;j++){
                   threshold += (double)pixels[i][j];
               }
           }
           System.out.print(threshold);
```

Comment: thanks i just realized this pretty much as soon as i posted it (always helps to type or talk out a problem, usual find that alone works out the answer) anyway you were right so ill accept answer

Comment: @user1110338 - If this is the correct answer to your question, mark it as such regardless whether you fixed it yourself or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a double `for` here. Something like this:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
        for(int i = 0; i < pixels[i].length; i++){
               threshold += (double)pixels[i][j];
        }
}
```

Comment: `+ =` is not an operator, `+=` is.

Comment: I took my -1 back, as you removed the error. I advise you to code in your IDE and then copy/paste your answer here. This will prevent such compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each row and column in the array, so you need 2 for-loops. What you're currently doing only covers the following: `(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), ...`.

This would work: (assuming a non-jagged array, at least for the threshold calculation)

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < pixels[i].length; j++)
{
   sum += pixels[i][j];
}
double threshold = (double)sum / (pixels.length * pixels[0].length);
System.out.print(threshold);
```

Or more simply: (assuming a non-jagged array, at least for the threshold calculation)

```
long sum = 0;
for (int[] i: pixels)
for (int j: i)
{
   sum += j;
}
double threshold = (double)sum / (pixels.length * pixels[0].length);
System.out.print(threshold);
```

Answer (score 0):

HINT

You have a 2D array, So to add each element you need to traverse each column of each row. For this 2 for loops might be of some use.

traverse over each value and add them

exit loop

Divide your sum with number of elements to get average (you may need to give some thought to type casting here)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a double when you count sum of ints, this is a waste, use long, it's faster

```
    long sum = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (int[] a : pixels) {
        for (int e : a) {
            sum += e;
            n++;
        }
    }
    double avg = ((double) sum) / n;
```

Comment: a little optimization: `n += a.length;` before inner loop ;)